Databricks: is there a way to forward incoming records over to SQL Server?
We are building a "typical" Medallion Architecture delta lake using Azure Databricks.
We have a business requirement to forward the incoming records over to a SQL Server instance as soon as a given record arrives at a Delta table. We have looked at the concept of "Change Data Feed", but it appears to be "gathering" the change data rather than just forwarding the records upon arrival.
We are using Delta Live Tables (DLT) framework to facilitate the transformations between the Bronze and Silver delta tables.
Is there a method by which every record hitting the Silver table is forwarded onto an external SQL Server instance as soon as it arrives at that Silver table?

No simple way.YET. Reason is currently DLT doesn't allow installation of maven packages which allows you to use spark to write to SQL. And DLT is not very python friendly. One option I can think of is to write a separate notebook run as a task within a workflow AFTER your DLT and use a readstream to read the DLT table and writestream to write only the new data to your Azure SQL. The checkpoint will keep track of what has been written and will only write new data.

Could you please provide what approach you have tried and expected output.
